# How to deploy a model saved via "happytransformer" to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, deployment, pytorch, aws-code-deploy

The problem goes as follows:
A GPT-NEO model was fined-tuned offline and saved using the Happy Transformers python package, I searched the web for a proper way to deploy it to AWS so it can be integrated into a website.

There documentation around this topic is very lacking and unless I write my own Pytorch or Tensorflow model I haven't found any reasonable solution except creating a Docker container with the models and somehow deploying that container to AWS and serving it using Lambdas.

Is there any proper way to solve such cases when I have TF / PT models that are wrapped with a higher level class that need to be served?